# lwjgl 101: How can I write applets?

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl

I have a working app in lwjgl. It doesn't do much yet; I've just started, but it does compile and run like it's supposed to. I want to make it into an applet. I've followed the guide [here](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/doku.php/lwjgl/tutorials/applet), and I have an applet that runs nicely and displays text and such in the applet area and can access the functions of lwjgl (like Sys.alert), but I can't figure out how to get opengl to actually render. I've tried extending an AWTGLCanvas and calling `this.add(myAWTGLCanvas)`, where `this` is the Applet that I'm using, but... nothing. The `initGL(`) and `paintGL()` methods never get called. I wonder if I'm supposed to be doing something with Display, but that's not for applets, right? Help?

Also: This counts as a "beginner" question, right?

Edit: [Here's](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-2ed4c1df.html) a simplified version of what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the source code for GearsApplet. Since lwjgl is open-source, you expletive, you can actually do that!
https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/test/applet/GearsApplet.java
Here is the source.